# How to use a nested inner join statement?

Tags: sqlite

I have created three tables such that:

```
CREATE TABLE guest(

name varchar(100),
ranking int,
PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE room(

 roomname varchar(100),
 wallcolor varchar(100),
 rating int,
 PRIMARY KEY(roomnane)
 );

 CREATE TABLE reservation(

 name varchar(100),
 roomname varchar(100),
 day varchar(100),
 moveinday int,
 moveoutday int,
 PRIMARY KEY(roomname, day, start, finish),
  FOREIGN KEY(roomname) REFERENCES room(roomname),
  FOREIGN KEY(name) REFERENCES guest(name)
 );
```

I am trying to write a DELETE query to delete all the guests that are not qualified to rent any room.  Qualified to rent means the guests ranking is greater than or equal to room ranking. Pretty much delete the reservation entry, and the guest too if they don't qualify

I tried

```
 DELETE 
 FROM
 reservation, guest
 INNER JOIN (
 SELECT
    reservation.roomname,
    reservation.day,
    reservation.start,
    reservation.finish
FROM
    guest
INNER JOIN reservation ON reservation.name = guest.name
INNER JOIN room ON reservation.roomname = room.roomname
WHERE
    room.rating > guest.ranking 
) invalidReservationTable  
ON reservation.roomname = invalidReservationTable.roomname
AND reservation.day = invalidReservationTable.day
AND reservation.start = invalidReservationTable.start
AND reservation.finish = invalidReservationTable.finish;
```

I am getting an error when I run this on sqlite on the Inner Join statement following the FROM reservation line. What am I doing wrong? Am I on the right track to delete just the reservation?

Comment: Try delete from reservastion where exists(select your joins here )

Comment: But what if the guest qualifies for another room? And don't mix implicit and explicit join syntax. In fact, don't use implicit syntax at all.

Comment: @Strawberry I said any room.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry thats what I meant. I corrected the original now

Comment: Mysql and sqlite are 2 different products, which one do you use?

Comment: How could I write this query? Am I on the right track? @Strawberry I need to delete all guests who are not qualified to rent any room, together
with their reservations

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this dialect.

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Oh, there is no multi-table delete in sqlite

Comment: @Shadow Is there CASCADE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot delete from multiple tables in same statement. Consider separating into two action queries: first on `reservations` table due to foreign key constraints, then on `guests` table, adding a `WHERE` clause subquery that conditions to your needs.

First, reservations delete:

```
DELETE FROM reservation
WHERE name IN 
  (SELECT reservation.name 
   FROM guest 
   INNER JOIN reservation ON reservation.name = guest.name 
   INNER JOIN room ON reservation.roomname = room.roomname        
   WHERE room.rating > guest.ranking);
```

Then guests table delete. However, the guest's corresponding reservation would no longer exist per query before. Hence, you should now remove guests without any reservations which you can handle with `LEFT JOIN...NULL`.

```
DELETE FROM guest 
WHERE name IN 
  (SELECT guest.name 
   FROM guest 
   LEFT JOIN reservation ON reservation.name = guest.name 
   WHERE reservation.name IS NULL)
```

By the way, reconsider design here. In one-to-many relationships, the many-to-many table should be the only delete interaction. Guests (who may make future reservations) should not be regularly cleaned out. And have your app/script validate ranking/rating prior to making reservation.

Comment: Where do you get invalidReservationTable from? Its not a table in my original three tables. Its something I got from inner join?

Comment: I am getting the error "invalidReservationTable" found. How do I declare it?

Comment: I removed it as you do not need such the derived table.

Comment: Thanks it removes from the reservation, but not from guest. Is there anything, I need to add?

Comment: Indeed, the reservation just deleted also took with it the guest.name to join on. Use a `LEFT JOIN ... NULL` to remove Guests without any reservations. See update.